# How can I draw 3D bound box in rviz tool

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'd like draw 3D bounding boxes for detected objects (car, people, etc.)

[image: Imgur]

In my googling, there is a visulization_marker in rviz that can draw a line.

However, it looks not a perfect solution to draw 3D bounding box,

Is there any suggested method to draw it.

Thanks in advanced

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296656/how-can-i-draw-3d-bound-box-in-rviz-tool./) by [adioshun](https://answers.ros.org/users/36325/adioshun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use the BoundingBox-Marker from the [jsk_rviz_plugins](http://jsk-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jsk_visualization/doc/jsk_rviz_plugins/plugins/bounding_box.html). [image description http://jsk-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/bounding_box2.png](http://jsk-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/bounding_box2.png)

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adioshun](https://answers.ros.org/users/36325/adioshun/) on 2018-07-09**:
Thanks I will try it